# Python3 error with str and byte code object

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, byte, nltk

So I tried to write a simple function to clean a text and summarize it:

```
def getTextWaPo(url):
page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
text = ' '.join(map(lambda p: p.text, soup.find_all('article')))
return text.encode('ascii', errors='replace').replace("?"," ")
```

but for this piece of code I get this error :

```
  File "Autosummarizer.py", line 12, in getTextWaPo
  return text.encode('ascii', errors='replace').replace("?"," ")
  TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

  line 12 ==> text = getTextWaPo(articleURL)
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are encoding data in line 12 using you have to use bytes. as `replace(b"?", b" ")`

The code look like

```
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def getTextWaPo(url):
    page = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
    text = ' '.join(map(lambda p: p.text, soup.find_all('article')))
    return text.encode('ascii', errors='replace').replace(b"?",b" ")
getTextWaPo("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

Answer (score 0):

You must change your last line

    `return text.encode('ascii', errors='replace').replace("?"," ")`

to

    `return text.encode('ascii', errors='replace').replace(b"?", b" ")`

because after the `encode()` you're operating on `bytes`, and must replace bytes with other bytes.